# IntelliJ Code Style Indentation Options seem to be ignored

Tags: intellij-idea, auto-indent

I am lost here..
In IntelliJ under Preferences/Editor/Code Style 
I've set Tab size, Indent, Continuation Indet to 2, respectively.

Then in my code file I select a block of code and do

Code/Auto-indent Lines

It seems to ignore my settings and instead still uses 4 spaces instead of 2. Why? What am I missing?